# NativeScript, WebView show local HTML file if offline

Tags: webview, nativescript

In NativeScript how do I show a local HTML file if the WebView is offline.

In this example I try to load a string instead of a file. But I can't get this to work ether.

```
    let errorHtml = `
        <html>
            <style>
                body {
                    background-color: red;
                    color: #fff;
                }
            </style>
            <body>
                <h1>Error</h1>
            </body>
        </html>
    `;

    webView.on(webViewModule.WebView.loadFinishedEvent, (args) => {
        if (!args.error) {
            loadLanguagesInWebView();
            listenLangWebViewEvents();
        } else {
            webView.src = errorHtml;
        }
    });

    webView.src = "www.google.com";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have included HTML files locally within your app, you don't have to worry whether the device is offline.

If you are asking about loading a remote website when device is offline, then it has nothing to do with the WebView.

It's all you have to do with your web app, implement [Service Worker API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API). I use Angular for my web apps, all I had do was to enable the [service worker](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-intro) module to get offline support for my web app. Depending on your web app's tech stack, you might have to do similar adjustments.

Comment: I have a WebView loading a site from a server. But I like to show an “offline” page (html file local) saying something like “there is no internet connection”.

Comment: If the site is not in your possession, then you can just listen to WebView's `loadFinished` event and if there is an error and [connectionType](https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-framework-modules/connectivity) is `none`, then set the error message on WebView.

Comment: I updated the question with the code I have today. But I can't get the error page to show if the main page (exemple google.com) is not loaded.

Comment: It seems to work just fine for me - [Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=MTZouO)

Comment: But if I set my phone on flight mode and restart the app the error page is not show up. Its is just blank. How do I get the error page show up if there is no connection?